# Freqency table from multiple lists

Tags: frequency

I have a data frame containing a list of genes from 60 different high throughput experiments. It looks something like this

```
experiment 1            experiment 2             
APOE                        DAPK
PAK                         POA2
GALC                        APOE
JNK
```

And this goes on for 60 experiments, with a total of about 5000 genes.

I simply want a list of genes that occur most frequently across all these lists, and from which datasets that gene is found in.  For example, the output might look like this...

```
Gene    Frequency    Present_In
APOE        4        experiment 5, experiment 11, experiment 27, experiment 53
SNCA        3        experiment 2, experiment  43, experiment 48
MAPT        3        experiment 5, experiment 44, experiment 57
GAK         2        experiment 23, experiment 31
```

I've been trying to do this for 5 hours!

[This is what my environment looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtcQk.png)

EDIT - This is the online tool I've been using that does what I need.
http://molbiotools.com/listcompare.html

I copy paste each gene list into the website and it spits out what I need. But I'm nearing 70 gene lists and I need R to do it automatically. Otherwise whenever I add a new list I have to re-copy paste all 70 gene lists 0.o

Comment: can you share what you have done so far?

Comment: I've tried a million different thing, but nothing has really worked. So I'm basically still at square one. I included a picture so you can see what I'm looking at

Comment: The only semi useful thing I've done is this, to split rows by commas and remove duplicates  library(zoo)
library(splitstackshape)
data <- cSplit(d, 1:ncol(d), "long", sep = ",")
data = distinct(data)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to implement this on R, but in languages like Python I'd use a `dict` with string keys (gene) and as value a `tuple` that contains a `dict` with experiment names (you'll build the list with this) and the count of appearances.
You would go about all lists sequentially, and each gene on each, and for each gene you would increment the counter and define the experiment in the experiment `dict`. Afterwards you'll iterate that `dict` printing the name of the gene, the count and the keys of the experiment `dict`. You can obviosly sort them by count, tho it may need conversion.

Comment: This is the closest sem-useful looking thing I've seen                        as.data.frame(table(unlist(data)))